# Setting custom Font (override the system UI font) for an entire SWT application UI

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, font-size

**Scenario:**

We have a java desktop application written using SWT where the UI was designed with windows XP default fonts and layout in mind. Now that we also have user who use the application on windows 7, some of the UI elements in the SWT java app dont show complete text captions. This is due to the fact that in WIN XP the default font is Tahoma 8 where as in WIN 7 It is Segoe 9.

**Problem :**

We would like to set/modify the font for our SWT application without setting the font for each and every widget (we have about hundreds of Screens with 20-30 widgets so its not practical). Ideally the best way would be to overwrite the system font that is read by SWT (Display class) and use a specified font.

**Ideal Solution**

Some way to set the font just as you set the look and feel using swing for the entire application.

Thanks in advance.

J

Comment: You can assign the custom font to a variable using `Font myFont = createFont(int fontFormat, File fontFile);`, and just refer to it wherever a font can be specified. As for an auto-setup, **i'm unsure**, but afraid it might not be practical (it might require more work to setup the auto-setup than to just specify the font on each component).